# (Bugzilla + Nginx) Nginx не может обработать длинный запрос

Tags: nginx

При попытке сохранить фильтр поиска в Bugzilla 4.4.4 - nqinx выплевывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом просто поиск выполняется без проблем.
Если в фильтре отменить выбор пары атрибутов, то все гуд

К сожалению слабо понимаю что да как происходит в кишках, поэтому извиняюсь за скудный набор данных. Может просто кто сталкивался.

Comment: загляните в error.log и посмотрите, возможно выделено слишком мало ресурсов для заголовков от клиента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснил: используется nginx-proxy в котором по умолчанию применен маленький объем буфера.

Для устранения проблемы в файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```bsh
http{ 
        ...
#    в конце блока  
#    добавить две строчки:  
    proxy_buffers 8 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;

#    или чтобы наверняка:      
    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    }
```

---

[Andrey Mihalev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/263405/andrey-mihalev), спасибо.